# How to create excel 2013 timeline from access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, late-binding

It's my first question here so please be easy on me..
I'm trying to create an excel report from a dataset i've created in MS Access as part of a MS-Access based large project.
This project has to run on many machines and to avoid reference errors i use late-binding.
My problem is that when i try to create (from Access) a Timeline using the "Slicercaches.add2" method my code fires error "5". As a test i've created the timeline from Excel-vba and i found that if i use the "XlTimeline" constant it works, but if i use the "2" value not . Is there a way to use the Xltimeline constant inside Access-Vba without reference to excel libraries??

Thanx in advance
MF

Comment: It would help here to show the code you're using, and also to add what version(s) of excel you're working with or need to be able to support.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Without seeing your VBA code, answering your question would mostly be speculation.  As a common practice, it is always beneficial to show the code you're working with (same concept as a picture is worth 1000 words).  With that being said, working with Excel objects (or any other office application) requires that you import the necessary libraries.  With the Excel library imported, you can essentially do anything to an excel file using the Excel object.  Is there a particular reason you would like to refrain from using the Excel library?